# How to uninstall kwin without installing openbox?

Tags: apt, window-manager, openbox, kwin

I haven't found anything about this anywhere, but when I remove kwin it automatically installs openbox for me and vice versa without me having any say in it. I realise this is to prevent users from screwing up their system, but I would like to use sawfish as my window manager exclusively.

So is this even possible with apt?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: If that's what you want to do, you should be installing from alternate with no DE at all

Comment: theres no way to just remove both?

Comment: @TimothyDuane If you have certain GUI components, you have to also have a window manager to support them. If you just want to not have `kwin`, and have `sawfish`, Raja's answer should do the trick. Hopefully. Or did you already try that, and it's not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing `sawfish` and make it the default window manager. After doing that, uninstall `kwin` (which is provided by the `kde-window-manager` package).